# How to get the element from a view-source: page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have made a small Chrome extension which has a click event listener that captures the element and then it gives the xpath.

But this is not capturing anything on a `view-source:` page.

Is there any way by which I can capture the element from `view-source:` page in JavaScript?

I am trying with this code on my content page:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function xyz(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //alert(e);
  var target = e.target || event.srcElement;
  var attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.attributes).map(function(i) {
    return [String(i.name)+": "+String(i.value)]
  })
  alert(attributes);
  prompt("xpath1 :",getPathTo(target));
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"captureElement",data:attributes});   
},true)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you can do, you can't interact with those pages.

Extensions cannot get access to `view-source:` protocol pages (it's not a [supported scheme](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)), so you can't inject a content script in them at all, even with `"<all_urls>"` filter.